# heroku rails use Elasticsearch Gem::LoadError sqlite3 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

rails app use `gem 'searchkick'`

run :

```
heroku addons:open bonsai
heroku config:set ELASTICSEARCH_URL=`heroku config:get BONSAI_URL`
heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

occur issue

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'searchkick', '~> 1.4'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.5'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

database.yml:

```
    default: &default
      adapter: sqlite3
      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000

    development:
      <<: *default
      database: db/development.sqlite3
    test:
      <<: *default
      database: db/test.sqlite3

    production:
      <<: *default
      database: db/production.sqlite3
```

model:

```
article.rb

class Article < ApplicationRecord

  searchkick
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :node
  has_attached_file :article_img, styles: { index_img: "300x300>", show_img: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :article_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

that occur database sqlite3 should do ?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `sqlite3` adapter for production environment but in `Gemfile` you have mentioned to use `pg` databse in production and `sqlite` only in development. So you need to fix either `Gemfile` or `database.yml` on your use basis.

Comment: solve that, run `heroku run rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product`

Comment: heroku doesn't use your database.yml

Comment: production:
          <<: *default
          adapter: :postgresql
          database: db/production.sqlite3